# Spring @Aspect & Maven. Not working in external modules, but it's working witouth annotations

Tags: java, spring, maven, aop, aspectj

I've a question about Spring AOP and AspectJ, defining aspects, pointcut etc with annotations.

The context is this:

- I have 2 maven modules (A and B).
- Module B uses module A (via `<dependency>...</dependency>` in maven) and import his spring context.
- I'm trying to write and use an very stupid test aspect (catch all public operations).
- This aspect is defined in module A,
- I wan't that this aspect works when I call any public operation in A or B.

Well, now the "postergeist". My first aproach was define all in XML. Aspect, pointcut, etc. And it works really well. This is the code:

**ApplicationContext**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="myAspectAOP" ref="myAspect">
        <aop:around method="validateCall"
            pointcut="execution(public * *(..))" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage"/>      

</beans>
```

*MyAspect.java* and *Test.java* is the same that the next case (without Aspect annotations). I don't put it here yet to avoid spreading much text.

That works fine!

Ok, next aproach. Using annotations. This is the code:

**ApplicationContext**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage"/>      
</beans>
```

And **MyAspect** class

```
@Aspect
@Component //I have tried without this annotation, and it doesn't work
public class MyAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
    public void allPublic() {
    }

    @Around("allPublic()")
    public Object validateCall(final ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {

    // Some Code

    }
}
```

**Test.java** (package com.mypackage)

```
@Component
public class Test{
    public void foo(){
    //Some code
    }
}
```

In this case:

- when I put **Test.java** into **module B** and call an public operation (remember, class is in B module), it **doesn't work**.
- BUT when I put **Test.java** into **A Module** and I call a public operation (It's in A module), it **works**. It looks like only works with calls to public operations of classes defined into the same module where Aspect is defined (A module), but not in "externals" (B Module). Remember. B module includes/uses A Module and import his context. But it isn't happening when I use "xml declaration" instead of "annotations declaration"
- Important: **MyAspect.java** is in **A Module** allways

Remember, in the first case (defining all in applicationContext, and not using @Aspect @Pointcut,@...) works allways, in B and A module public operations.

In both cases, the classes are into *com.mypackage*, so are injected by spring.

I'm really lost, It's the first time I get this kind of "postergeist", and I have been looking and looking into Spring documentation an google for days, but I can't find any solution.

I'm using Spring 3.1.2 and Aspectj 1.6.11

Please, any idea?

Thanks!